# Setting up a client to use a local DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dns-hosting, dnsmasq

I have an Ubuntu Server (20.04) (SERVER) on which I'm running dnsmasq. This machine has a local IP of SERVERADDRESS

I have a Macbook Pro (CLIENT) on the same network - and I updated the DNS rules on the MBP to point to SERVERADDRESS

I can nslookup any domain on the CLIENT and it resolves fine. However, if I try to nslookup SERVERADDRESS, it says server can't find it. Also, it spits it out in reverse like SSERDDAREVRES.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN

Also - I tried to set up a custom domain on SERVER of example.com. WHen I run nslookup example.com on the SERVER, I get back

```
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Name:   example.com
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

As expected

However, when I do the same on CLIENT I get

```
Server:     SERVERADDRESS
Address:    SERVERADDRESS#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   example.com
Address: 93.184.216.34
```

Which is not expected, given they should both be using the same DNS (the server).

Is there something additional I need to do on the CLIENT to force it to use the SERVER DNS?

EDIT: Adding output of dig from both machines per comments
Note: SERVERADDRESS is a local IP address (192.168. ...)
On Server:

```
USERNAME@SERVERNAME:/$ dig example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27740
;; flags: qr aa rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        0   IN  A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 20 18:21:35 CST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

```
USERNAME@SERVERNAME:/$ dig example.com @SERVERADDRESS

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> example.com @SERVERADDRESS
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45224
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: d71c1a5e56f69c9e010000006008ca08a1e5d4fd5b1af968 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        81320   IN  A   93.184.216.34

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.5#53(192.168.1.5)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 20 18:25:44 CST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 84
```

On Client:

```
CLIENTMACHINENAME:~ CLIENTUSERNAME$ dig example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30613
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        81427   IN  A   93.184.216.34

;; Query time: 62 msec
;; SERVER: SERVERADDRESS#53(SERVERADDRESS)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 20 19:23:57 EST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

```
CLIENTMACHINENAME:~ CLIENTUSERNAME$ dig example.com @192.168.1.5

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> example.com @SERVERADDRESS
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44288
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        81331   IN  A   93.184.216.34

;; Query time: 36 msec
;; SERVER: SERVERADDRESS#53(SERVERADDRESS)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 20 19:25:33 EST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

Here is my systemd-resolved config file:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
#DNS=8.8.8.8
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#Cache=yes
DNSStubListener=no
ReadEtcHosts=yes
```

Comment: First of all, to test a DNS server, don't use `nslookup`, since this tool processes and interprets queries and responses. To see how your DNS server really reacts, use `dig` or `host`. Having said that, it would seem that the server doesn't correctly perform reverse DNS resolution. 93.184.216.34 is the "official" name resolution for example.com, from IANA.

Comment: Try `dig example.com` and `dig @SERVERADDRESS example.com` on both CLIENT and SERVER.

Comment: Regarding the problems with nslookup, see https://jdebp.uk/FGA/nslookup-flaws.html.

Comment: Thanks - I posted the results of dig for both scenarios above

Comment: It looks like SERVER configures a different DNS server at 127.0.1.1 than at 192.168.1.5. The loopback address probably refers to `systemd-resolved`, which is enabled on more recent Ubuntus by default. Check how `systemd-resolved` is configured. It should normally forward queries to some other DNS server, but perhaps it's hardwired to resolve example.com to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Ah I think I get it - how would I check the configuration of `systemd-resolved`?

Comment: See the `resolved.conf` file documented at https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/resolved.conf.html.